# open new window from a list

Tags: android, listview, window, new-operator

i have made a list of countries and i want it to open a new window when one of its item clicked, and i cant make it do that =/ 
here is my java code

```
public class Country_list extends ListActivity{<br>
    @Override<br>
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {<br>
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub<br>
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);<br>
        setContentView(R.layout.main);<br>

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.imageView1,
                getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country)));
    }
  private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_country,parent, false);

            String[] items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country);

            ImageView iv= (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            tv.setText(items[position]);

            if(items[position].equals("English")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_english_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("French")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_france_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("German")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_german_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Turkish")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_turky_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Chinese")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_china_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Italian")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_italy_h);
            }
            else if(items[position].equals("Russian")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_russia);
            }
            return row;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's your exact requirement, you need own activity for each elements in the Listview?

Comment: Okay, you have to add a item click listener for your list and then inside click handler you can initiate a new Activity with the help of intent. But i don't know what you have achieved, are you able to see the list in your application ?

Comment: @Aerrow to get it open another class that contain a list of words of the selected country language

Comment: @user1283769 : you can open a popupwindow instead of an new Activity

Comment: @rajesh.adhi: yes i can here is how it looks:[image]http://i43.tinypic.com/11rdn4h.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `OnItemClickListener` in your main activity which holds the list

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("data1", "countryname");
    intent.putExtra("data2", "countryCode");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you want to pass data to the second activity specify them in the putExtra function, you can retrieve the data inside the second activity like this

```
String data1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("data1");
String data2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("data2");
```

Make sure that you add the secondactivity in the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
     <intent-filter >
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope this will help.